# How to customize Jackson ObjectMapper to allow NaN in Spring Boot 2.0?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

Moving this here from [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10500) as the Spring team only uses GitHub issues for bugs and feature requests.

Per the Spring Boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper), it should be possible to customize the Jackson `ObjectMapper` using environment properties (e.g. in `application.properties`) such as `spring.jackson.parser.<feature_name>` as long as you're not defining your own `ObjectMapper` bean.

I need to activate the `ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS` parser features as I'm getting (strictly speaking invalid) JSON with `NaN` values for floating point fields that I want Jackson to map to `java.lang.Double.NaN` in Java.

So in my `application.properties` I've added `spring.jackson.parser.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS=true` and I can see this is being picked up:

- Spring Boot's `JacksonAutoConfiguration` is creating an `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`
- `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`'s  `StandardJackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` is picking up my `spring.jackson.parser.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS=true` property and adding it to its `features` map
- `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`'s `build()` method is eventually calling `configureFeature` which results in the mask value of the `ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS` feature (512) being added to the `_parserFeatures` value in the `JsonFactory` of the `ObjectMapper`
- the `ObjectMapper` being injected in my bean using `@Autowired` also has the `ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS` feature enabled

What's unclear is why I'm still getting the following Jackson error when parsing JSON that has the `NaN` value for a floating point field:
`JSON decoding error: Character N is neither a decimal digit number, decimal point, nor "e" notation exponential mark.`

I'm debugging now so I'll probably end up answering my own question. The above detail is to possibly help people coming from [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10500) to find a thread to pull on in case their feature flags aren't being applied.

Comment: Instead of using `BigDecimal` as a type you can use `Number`. When you enable `DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS` feature `Jackson` will create `BigDecimal` instance for floating point numbers. In code you can create extra getter `getValueAsBigDecimal` and convert `Number` instance to `BigDecimal` or cast. In case of `NaN` it will be a `Decimal` instance and you can return `null` if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "problem" is that I'm trying to map float values to `BigDecimal` in Java, but `BigDecimal` has no representation for `NaN` (or `(-)Inf` for that matter). The problem originates in `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.TokenBuffer.Parser` which in `public BigDecimal getDecimalValue()` does:

```
    return BigDecimal.valueOf(n.doubleValue());
```

which ends up (in `java.match.BigDecimal`) converting the double value to a String `"NaN"` and which is then passed into the `BigDecimal` constructor, which rejects it with a `NumberFormatException` and the error message I mentioned in the question:

```
throw new NumberFormatException("Character " + c
    + " is neither a decimal digit number, decimal point, nor"
    + " \"e\" notation exponential mark.");
```

In my case, I would be happy with `NaN` being mapped to `null`, but I understand that's not the correct behavior for everyone using Jackson, so I've written a custom deserializer to do just that:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class NaNSafeBigDecimalDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<BigDecimal> {

    private BigDecimal nanValue = null;

    @Override
    public BigDecimal deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        if (p.isNaN()) {
            return nanValue;
        } else {
            return NumberDeserializers.BigDecimalDeserializer.instance.deserialize(p, ctxt);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can just annotate my `BigDecimal` fields with `@JsonDeserialize(using = NaNSafeBigDecimalDeserializer.class)`.